# Openvpn linux server, ok with linux,not with windows client

Tags: openvpn

This is my configuration of openvpn

The server is linux centos,the client1 is linux centos,the client2 is windows10.
Linux client can ping linux server,but not windows client
windows client can ping linux server,but not linux client
linux client can ping linux server,but not windows client.
What I miss?No error on syslog,I have tried to turnoff firewall on windows
but no success.
Those are files conf

server linux

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

client linux

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote mysite.fqdn 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 6
```

client windows

```
client 
proto udp 
verb 3 
dev tun 
remote mysite.fqdn
port 1194 
ca ca.crt
cert windows10.mysite.crt
key windows10.mysite.key
tls-auth ta.key 1
nobind 
persist-key 
persist-tun
cipher AES-256-CBC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found: on server must add

client-to-client and some other stuff

for windows client(as usual..)

so server.conf is

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
client-to-client
topology "subnet"
push "topology subnet"
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
```